# Aggregating json data with pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

I'm currently working with pyspark and the great language game dataset which contains several samples as json objects like the one shown below.

Each of this samples represents an instance of the game, where some person has listened an audio file with some spoken language and afterwards should choose out of four possible languages which one she just heard.

I want now to aggreagte all this games on let's say the "target" field and the "guess" field and afterwards count the amount of games for each pair ("target","guess").
Can someone give me some help on how to get this done?

I already had a look at the pyspark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD), but as I'm quite new to to python/pyspark it didn't really understand how the aggregate funciton works.

```py
{"target": "Turkish", "sample": "af0e25c7637fb0dcdc56fac6d49aa55e",
 "choices": ["Hindi", "Lao", "Maltese", "Turkish"],
 "guess": "Maltese", "date": "2013-08-19", "country": "AU"}
```

Comment: could you please post a sample of the input data and the expected output data ?

Comment: You might read all jsons in a spark dataframe, groupby on the two columns and count the number of occurences.

Answer (score 0):

The process of converting json data into pyspark dataframe can be done this way.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import json

sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf())
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

def convert_single_object_per_line(json_list):
    json_string = ""
    for line in json_list:
        json_string += json.dumps(line) + "\n"
    return json_string

json_list = [{"target": "Turkish", "sample": "af0e25c7637fb0dcdc56fac6d49aa55e",
 "choices": ["Hindi", "Lao", "Maltese", "Turkish"],
 "guess": "Maltese", "date": "2013-08-19", "country": "AU"}]


json_string = convert_single_object_per_line(json_list)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([json.loads(line) for line in json_string.splitlines()])


[In]:df
[Out]:
DataFrame[choices: array<string>, country: string, date: string, guess: string, sample: string, target: string]
[In]:df.show()
[Out]:
+--------------------+-------+----------+-------+--------------------+-------+
|             choices|country|      date|  guess|              sample| target|
+--------------------+-------+----------+-------+--------------------+-------+
|[Hindi, Lao, Malt...|     AU|2013-08-19|Maltese|af0e25c7637fb0dcd...|Turkish|
+--------------------+-------+----------+-------+--------------------+-------+
```